# FCM Notification iOS not working when app is in background or terminated

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I saw this question multiple times but none of the answers worked for me.

applicationReceivedRemoteMessage gets called when app is in foreground.

I set content_available to true and priority high in my payload.

I set background modes in capabilities for remote notifications. Tried removing it still didn't work.

Implemented didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and when I setAPNSToken for sandbox or unknown or prod I can't even receive the notifications when app is in foreground. If I don't set anything then I get notifications when app is in foreground but not in background or inactive.

The certificates I uploaded into fcm project are valid and configured properly.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried also setting a background mode of remote fetch? You cannot receive pushes when the app has been terminated.

Comment: Same with me . I have set 1.PushNotification = ON 2.background mode = ON 3.Set valid APNS certificate . But still it works for Foreground but not in background

Answer (score 1):

`FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()` try this inside `applicationDidEnterBackground` method of app delegate this will work for me.